# How to say something is $O(\sqrt{\log n})$ in word?

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, asymptotics

When something is $O(\log n)$ we say it's logarithmic in $n$. How can we say it in "word" when something is $O(\sqrt{\log n})$?

Comment: “Sub-logarithmic”?

Comment: We (human kind) don't seem to have a term for that.

Comment: I would say "sublogarithmic" or "root-log", depending on how much detail I wanted to convey.  But "root log" sounds botanically stupid: trees have roots and have logs, but...

Comment: I guess "big-O-of-the-square-root-of-log-n" or "something in the order of the square root of $\log(n)$".

Answer (score 0):

In theoretical computer science we call an algorithm that runs in $O((\log n)^c)$ time for some constant $c > 0$ a [polylogarithmic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithmic_function) algorithm or "polylog" for short.